# Frequency counts with a "multiple selection" variable

Tags: r, count, frequency, multipleselection, crosstable

I have a dataframe with three variables:

1. ID
2. Gender (m,f,d)
3. Medication (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)

For "Medication" multiple selections were possible in the questionnaire so now there are several numbers in each cell of the dataframe (separated by ";").
Is it possible to create a frequency table that counts each number (1-10) individually  and have it grouped by gender? I need to have "Medication" (1-10) in rows and the counts grouped by gender as columns.

I already tried to split the columns so that each cell is left with only one value. But then I still have the problem to count the values across multiple columns. For each function I tried so far, the variables have been counted separately.

Thank you for your help!

[Sorry, I don't know how to do it with dput. Here is a screenshot, I hope that helps! (Geschlecht = gender; Medikament = medication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uoHzZ.png)

[And this is the expected output but without the combinations like "01;03"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wr8QW.png)

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example with `dput` and your expected output

Comment: just do `dput(your_data)` copy the results from R and paste it here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text parsing like this can be difficult without a specific, reproducible example. However, it sounds as though your data frame looks something like this:

```r
df
#>    ID medication gender
#> 1   1          9      f
#> 2   2      2;1;3      m
#> 3   3        6;2      d
#> 4   4          3      f
#> 5   5    7;8;7;1      f
#> 6   6    6;9;4;6      m
#> 7   7          9      d
#> 8   8      8;6;3      f
#> 9   9        9;7      d
#> 10 10        8;6      m
```

In which case, the pedestrian way to get your result in base R would be something like this:

```
meds <- lapply(split(df, df$gender), 
               function(x) unlist(strsplit(x$medication, ";\\s?")))

genders <- rep(c("d", "f", "m"), times = lengths(meds))

table(gender = genders, medication = unlist(meds))
#>       medication
#> gender 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
#>      d 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 2  0
#>      f 1 0 2 0 0 1 2 2 1  0
#>      m 1 1 1 1 0 3 0 1 1  0
```

---

**Reproducible data**

```r
set.seed(2)

medication <- sapply(rpois(10, 2), function(x) {
  if(x == 0) x <- 1
  x <- sample(1:10, x, TRUE)
  paste(x, collapse = ";")
})

gender <- sample(c("m", "f", "d"), 10, TRUE, prob = c(2, 2, 1))

df <- data.frame(ID = 1:10, medication = medication, gender = gender)
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: You may also do this in a single line `table(stack(setNames(strsplit(df$medication, ";"), df$gender))[2:1])`